# jQuery limiting the results

Tags: jquery

I want to limit the results to max 10 but my code below doesn't work. I get **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** error on line `var results = 'search-db.php';`

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#textbox_postcode').autocomplete(
            {
                var results = 'search-db.php';

                source: response(results.slice(0, 10));,
                minLength: 3
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="textbox_postcode" value="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, this is just not valid JavaScript. You cannot have an assignment statement inside an object literal. You can move it before the `.autocomplete()` call. Also I don't see why you would call `.slice` on a **string** for that purpose. And what is `response`? The `;` after it is invalid there as well. I recommend to get familiar with the basic syntax first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide.

Comment: I'm new in jQuery. It might look silly. I I leave it as `source: 'search-db.php', minLength: 3` then it works fine. I just need to limit the output.

Comment: Even more important that you read the documentation first before you try anything.

Comment: I'll read promise but how do I make this work?

Comment: Your best option is to make search-db.php limit the number of results it returns.  It's pretty silly to return a bunch of data to the client and then never use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already said in my comment, this is not valid JavaScript.

The [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) describes the various ways how to retrieve the data.

Since you want to limit the number of items shown, you have two possibilites:

- Let the server return only 10 items. This would be the most sensible solution since you avoid transferring data you won't use anyway.
- Use a callback as `source`, make the Ajax request and prepare the data accordingly.

Here is an example for the second solution:

```
$('#textbox_postcode').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, callback) {
        $.getJSON('search-db.php', request).then(function(items) {
            // success
            callback(items.slice(0,10));
        }, function() {
            // error - callback must always be called as per documentation
            callback([]);
        });
    },
    minLength: 3
});
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  My vote is still for limit on the server side.

Comment: I always LIMIT in SQL but at this time I wanted to learn how to do with jQuery.